# TypeError: xxxxx method is not a function NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I know this question kind of already exists, but the answers did not rectify my problem.
The error is "TypeError: xxxxx is not a function";

Folder V1

**V1/base/common.js**

`exports.xxx = async () => { };`

**V1/one.js**

`const {xxx} = require(./base/common);`

**Above code is working fine**

But when I copied the same file in different folder named **v2** and tried to import the method it is not working

*Below is the folder structure*

**V2/base/common.js**

`exports.xxx = async () => { };`

**V2/two.js**

`const {xxx} = require(./base/common);`

when I try to run v2/two.js getting error **TypeError: xxxxx method is not a function NodeJs**

Comment: is there any circular dependency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is creating new object in both V1 and V2

example : let obj1 = require('./base/common') in V1, let obj2 = require('./base/common') in V2

If someone has a better solution, I am all ears.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will not work properly as **You can have multiple named exports per module but only one default export.**

Note:: your ***Folder V1*** is working because you should be returning an object from function which contains **xxx**, btw in **V2** you could be exporting an object which do not contains any key named **xxx**,

for more in depth explanation you can refer to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: Nasiruddin Saiyed, thanks for the answer but I don't think ur answer explains my problem, I am using same `exports.xxx` in multiple places and it is not breaking there.

Comment: Nasiruddin Saiyed, I have 2 solutions that will work, one creating an object instead of destructuring and another lame one renaming the file in v2 folder.

Comment: Nasiruddin Saiyed, But thank u because of u came to know one new topic

Comment: I did it in simpler way, Hope it could resolve your problem, Happy Coding!